# Does a ball count if it hits an umpire?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating

What happens in a scenario where the batsman plays a shot down the ground and it hits the umpire? Isn't it unfair to the batsman to lose a certain boundary had there been one? Does the ball count as a dead ball?

Answer (score 8):

If the ball hits an on field umpire, it is **not** considered a dead ball **unless**:

- the ball lodges in the clothes of an umpire. ([Law 23.1.a.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20170623182949/https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-23-dead-ball/) at the time this question was written, [Law 20.1.1.5](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/dead-ball) as of 2023)
- a serious injury to an umpire occurs (after the ball hits to an umpire) (Law 23.4.b.2 at the time, Law 20.4.2.2 as of 2023)

In such cases, it will be a regular dead ball. i.e. the ball will be considered a legal ball but no more runs will be allowed to take to the batsman after that incident occurred.

Here is an example case for such incident:

See [this YouTube clip](http://youtu.be/AIib7_g9xOo). It occurred in the 1st ODI between [New Zealand and Bangladesh](http://www.espncricinfo.com/nzvbdesh/engine/match/300426.html?innings=1;view=commentary) in Auckland in 26-Dec-2007. See the ball 44.5 in the commentary. The ball was considered a normal ball.